# Adding resistor in parallel to digipot

Tags: i2c, opto-isolator, digital-potentiometer

I'm trying to control a device using a digital potentiometer (AD5245S). In my application I can't tie the low-ref of the potentiometer and ground, so I'm using an I2C optical isolator (ISO1541) to isolate digital potentiometer and power isolated circuit using potentiometer lo-ref and hi-ref.

Cirquit works fine, but I see noise on the wiper when any device is communicating using I2C. I was thinking that connecting SDA pullup to potentiometer low reference somehow messes the results (like connecting a resistor in parallel to potentiometer). Or maybe I just have digital noise, because I haven't added bypass capacitors to devices. Can you see what can cause this behaviour?

[image]

Comment: It's a common problem with digipots to let some data com traffic thru to the wiper.

Comment: @Andyaka can you fight that?

Comment: If your target circuit can tolerate capacitance from the wiper to it's local ground then yes.